# PHP Method chaining with dynamic names

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, methods, chaining

I was wondering if it's possible to create a method chaining using the values (or keys) of an array as the dynamic names of the methods.

For example, I have an array: 
`$methods = ['first', 'second', 'third']`

Is it possible to create the following call ?

```
first()->second()->third();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested. Something along the lines of:

```
$object = null; // set this to an initial object to call the methods on

foreach ($methods as $value)
{
    $object = $object->$value();
}
```

Note that each method you call should return an object that has a method to be called next. If it's an object of the same class - then it can just return itself with each chainable method.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for. The solution was way simpler than the one i was thinking about.

Comment: You're welcome, although you should probably replace "$value()" with some sort of other solution, like call_user_func(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score -1):

You can also use eval function.
Example:

```
$object = new SomeClass(); // first, second, third
$methods = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

$callStr = 'return $object->';

foreach($methods as $method){
    $callStr.= $method . '()->';
}

$callStr = substr($callStr, 0, -2);
$callStr.= ';'; // return $object->first()->second()->third();

$result = eval($callStr); // return result of call - $object->first()->second()->third();
```